# Programmatically turn on ASP.Net 4.5 in Windows 8?

Tags: asp.net-4.5

In windows 8 Consumer Preview, I can enable ASP.NET 4.5 in Turn Windows features on or off/.NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services/ASP.NET 4.5. To do this programmatically I used to run a Windows utility "pkgmrg.exe" in Windows 7, which requirs to specify the package name. Anyone knows the package name for ASP.NET 4.5 in Windows 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is dism.exe:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
```

Comment: Thank you Hao Kung for you answer which is exactly what I was looking for. In addition to above command, I use "dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45" to enable other ASP relating features in Application Development Features. Hope this is useful to someone else.